# Python BaseHTTPRequestHandler path with '#' character

Tags: python, server

I'm trying to do OAuth from the command line. I have a local web server that processes one request to grab the OAuth code. The local web server is extending `BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer` and the handler extends `BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler`. What I'm doing is very similar to doing OAuth2 with Google, except I'm not accessing the Google API. I am doing a simplified version of run_flow from [here](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/tools.py). I've tried the process with a Google client_id and request url (for example, 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth') and it works, the handler's `self.path` contains `/?code=xxxx` and I'm able to use that code by parsing `self.path` within the handler.

My problem is that when I use the other API, the handler's `self.path` is always only the `'/'` character. The API I'm accessing sends a redirect like so:
`HOST:PORT/#code=xxxx` while Google's redirect looks like `HOST:PORT/?code=xxxx`. I know the `#` character is a fragment identifier in URLs, but
does the `#` character somehow terminate the handler's reading of `self.path`? Is there a way to work around it and grab the `code`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A year later, but did you ever figure this out? I've run into a similar problem with the Facebook API and haven't had any luck finding a solution.

Comment: think I did a really gross workaround with javascript...don't really remember but it involved writing a script in the GET and parsing the token from window.location.href then sending that back to the server (basically i wouldn't suggest it)

Comment: Haha, I see. After I commented I kept searching and found another method (in Facebook OAuth API, no idea about Google) to get a code. More involved, but at least I can retrieve it in Python.